# MySQL group by a column depending on values from another column

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how to achieve such a query. Say for example I have the following table which tracks clicks on links coming from different ip addresses:

```
id      link       ip
1       Link 1     100.100.1.1
2       Link 1     100.100.1.2
3       Link 2     100.100.1.3
4       Link 1     100.100.1.1
5       Link 3     100.100.1.4
6       Link 3     100.100.1.1
```

What I want to do is get all unique ip clicks to the same link, so the result should look like:

```
id      link       ip
1       Link 1     100.100.1.1
2       Link 1     100.100.1.2
3       Link 2     100.100.1.3
5       Link 3     100.100.1.4
6       Link 3     100.100.1.1
```

I'm thinking I should group the table but doing so will remove duplicates from either the link or ip column. Is it possible to just like group all Link 1 IPs, Link 2, IPs, Link 3 IPs etc.

Hopefully that didn't sound too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `group by`:

```
select min(id) as id, link, ip
from t
group by link, ip;
```

In MySQL, you can *also* use this syntax:

```
select id, link, ip
from t
group by link, ip;
```

where `id` is in the `select` list but not in the `group by`.  Although allowed, I think this is a bad habit to get into in general (there are a few situations where this feature is useful).

Comment: Thank you, this does get me what I need. Now a follow up that I forgot to include in my original question. If I have another INT column that stores the timestamp when that click/row was recorded, how would I group the IPs under a certain link that were recorded like 1 hour in between? I want to discard duplicate ip clicks that were made in specified amount of time, but count them again if the click was made after that (like after an hour).

Comment: @georaldc . . . That is a very different question.  I suggest you ask it as another question.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try to get it working first before I open up a new question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct` would also work if you just wish you view the columns

no need for group